# Что значит слово ‹‹есмя››?

Tags: перевод

В контексте ‹‹Жаловать есмя своих холопов вольны, а и казнити вольны же››

Спасибо

Comment: По-моему, это глагол "есть" во множественном числе первого лица.

Comment: "аз есмь червь" что-то из "Недоросля" Фонвизина

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @[Victor Bazarov](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/5915/victor-bazarov), это древнерусская форма глагола «быть» в первом лице множественного числа настоящего времени, совр. рус. «мы есть». На самом деле, правильно было бы сказать *есмы́*, ст.сл. *ѥсмъ*, в *есмы́* окончание -мы под воздействием местоимения «мы», но и форма «есмя» была широко распространена.

Ваша цитата не совсем точна и не полна, вот её [правильный вид](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Hx58WrRwnhgC&pg=PT151&lpg=PT151&dq=%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B,%20%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B6%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=v-8mvsTWaB&sig=BnjMSBhMNosxOog-4dpBtrfv_vE&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBWoVChMI-YPUm4uayAIVgxIsCh0JHwaa#v=onepage&q=%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B6%D0%B5&f=false):

> А жаловати есмя своих холопей волны, а и казнити волны же есми были.

Как можно заметить, второй раз написано уже не «есмя», а «есми», что, в принципе, характерно для уровня грамотности московских писцов XV века. Оба эти слова являются вспомогательными глаголами и относятся к причастию «были» (в др.-рус. языке формы глагола на -л были причастиями), т. е. «есмя были», что является формой одного из прошедших времён, перфекта, от глагола «быти», как в современном английском «have been», и на современный русский переводится «[мы] были», современное русское прошедшее время происходит от древнерусского перфекта, формы настоящего времени глагола «быть» в современном русском перестали употребляться, а старые причастия на -л начали восприниматься как формы глагола прошедшего времени, хотя они до сих пор изменяются по родам, что характерно для причастия, а не глагола.

Таким образом, перевод этого предложения такой:

> А жаловать своих холопов мы всегда были вольны, вольны были и казнить.

Comment: Конечно же, "быть" а не "есть"... {redface}

Comment: @VictorBazarov - Да всё нормально, переводится-то он «есть». ;)

Comment: Нельзя такие предложения писать, по 94 слова, с одного раза не прочтёшь.

Comment: @mustaccio - Это дело привычки. :)

Answer (score 0):

"вольны" - это слово wolny из польского, в переводе "свободно, бесплатно" в данном контексте - "разрешено без ограничений", так как это мутация слова неграмотными писарями польского слова dozwolone - "разрешённый", "жаловать" - żałować "сожалеть" - такая же грамматическая ошибка, потому что переводчик неграмотный и посчитал "сожалеть" и "жалеть" одно и то же по смыслу, "**есмя**" - jesteśmy "**мы есть**", "же" - перепутано с że - "что", на самом деле смысл - też - "тоже, также". Буквальный перевод это фразы таков:

> *Мы можем жалеть своих холопов, но и казнить тоже.*

В переводе на русский эта фраза звучит так:

> *Мы имеем право своих холопов хвалить, а также имеем право их казнить.*

Comment: Жаловать - это не жалеть, это - награждать (особенно в форме пожаловать), или как минимум любить ("Жалует царь, да не жалует псарь"). Так что едва ли тут ошибка перевода.

Comment: Я только не совсем понял почему вы в качестве примера приводите польский